# Qt Label::setPixmap not working

Tags: c++, qt

Simple, I'm trying to display an image in a simple Qt GUI app.
I have this code:

```
ui->label_2->setVisible(true);
QPixmap supremect(":/images/supremecourt.jpg");
ui->label_2->setPixmap(supremect);
if(supremect.isNull())
{
    QMessageBox err(this);
    err.setText("File null");
    err.exec();
}
building=SPCT; // A flag
ui->label_2->show();
```

It compiles perfectly, but when I run it, nothing shows. I am sure that the image exists in the resources, so what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Converting to PNG does not help

Comment: Could it be you're missing the jpeg library?

Comment: Is the label's parent visible? If the parent is hidden, the child will remain hidden.

Comment: Yes, the function also makes some buttons visible

Comment: I can also test if the image is null, and it is not: `if(supremect.isNull()) cout << "NULL";`

Comment: I'll try converting them to png

Comment: Converting to PNG doesn't work, either.

Comment: Maybe the label's size is not managed by a layout or the layout sizes it to size 0x0? Does setting a text show something?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
QPixmap p;
QString str = ":/images/supremecourt.jpg";
bool retVal = p.load(str);
if(retVal == false)
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to load image!";
    foreach(const QByteArray &fmt, QImageReader::supportedImageFormats())
    {
        qDebug() << QString(fmt);
        // if this doesn't list jpeg then you don't have 
        // the plugin in your imageformats folder.
    }

    if( !QFile::exists(str) )
    {
        qDebug() << "File" << str << "doesn't exist!";
    }
}
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#load

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#exists

If it isn't loading, then your program probably doesn't have access to the right plug-in or the file doesn't exist where you think it does.

The dll for the jpeg plug-in is called qjpeg4.dll and should be in `./imageformats/`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. run it from some IDE (Qt Creator) and check logs. It is almost certain that some error message is shown there.
2. make sure that jpg plug in is loaded.
3. make sure that something else doesn't change content of label (for example setText will clear pixmap)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the image ( :/images/supremecourt.jpg ) to the [resource file](http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in/vs-addin-managing-resources.html) correctly? If you are not, watch [this](http://www.voidrealms.com/viewtutorial.aspx?id=184). Can you post your resource file's structure?

Comment: I tested for the file existing already, and checked if the image isNull()