# Qt quick deploy, empty window on running

Tags: windows, qt, deployment

I have a problem with launching application after deploy.
Build project, did copy all necesary files in release folder, the move it on another machine (if is important, I built it with MinGW 4.8 32 bits on Windows 8 64 bits and tried to run it on Windows XP 32 bits). However, when I tried to run it, it just shows a small white square.
I tried to use Qt Resource System. Created a .qrc file, here it is:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>qml/Rename_Files/Button.qml</file>
    <file>qml/Rename_Files/main.qml</file>
    <file>images/file_browser_icon_32x32.png</file>
    <file>images/file_renamer_icon_32x32.png</file>
</qresource>
```

and used resources accordingly:
viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml//Rename_Files/main.qml"));
"qrc:/images/file_browser_icon_32x32.png" & "qrc:/images/file_renamer_icon_32x32.png"
On build machine everything works.Now copy again everything on the other machine and try again. No change at all!
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to load an image at runtime in a deployment machine is usually a runtime plugin error.  If it can't find the appropriate imageformat dll, it won't load the image.

Create a folder called "imageformats" next to your exe and put the appropriate dll's in there to use all the image formats you are using in your program.

Find the dll's on your development machine in

```
<Qt Install Dir>\<Compiler>\plugins\imageformats
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#qt-plugins

So you probably need `qico.dll`.

If the above doesn't solve your problem, you may need to run "depends.exe" on your development machine to see if there are other dlls you need. Also you can do some additional debugging on your development machine to do runtime checks to make sure it can find the image:

[Qt Label::setPixmap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309835/qt-labelsetpixmap-not-working/16310198#16310198)

Hope that helps.

Comment: **qico.dll** didn't help me. Tomorrow I'll read a bit documentation of "depends" app.

Comment: Couldn't help it, I did run Dependency Walker on development machine, it was complaining about some IESHIMS.DLL. Then run Dependency Walker on target machine, and here is the result: http://postimg.org/image/m2f75gyrx/. That MPR.DLL is inside QT5CORE.DLL, so this seems to be the problem. I did copy again Qt5Core.dll and Qt5Cored.dll, but still got that error. Any ideea what's missing?

Comment: Assuming you are using msvc for your compiler, have you ran the appropriate MS redistributables package?

Comment: I said above that I'm using MinGW 4.8 32 bits, not MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. This thread http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56250-Empty-window-when-running-application-on-Windows-XP-32-bits?highlight=empty+window contains what I found through my research and Chris' help.
I apologise for very late response.

Comment: Athan, could you please clarify what exactly helped you? I tried his solution with Qt and QtQuick.2 folders, but realized that my deployment already has them.

Comment: @AlexPetrenko, it helped me to find a way to solve the problem. Most probably (Qt) folders aren't added by default, you need to copy those folders into release build folder. As I did then, you need to find application's requirements.  First try with a 'Hello world!' app. Create a release build, close qt creator, rename qt app folder, then try to run the app without libraries linked to Qt folder. Copy requirements one by one until you can run it. The same way you'll need to find requirements for your 'dev' app if you don't know them already. Process also explained in the link above.