# Why is QPixmap.load() failing even though it says that it doesnt?

Tags: c++, qt

Why is the following happening?

```
QPixmap getUnknownPixmap(){
    QPixmap pix;
    if (!pix.load(":/resources/Unknown.jpg")){
        //this doesnt print out
        printf("ERROR ----------------- COULD NOT LOAD UNKNOWN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
        fflush(0);
    }
    if (pix.isNull()){
        //this prints out
        printf("ERROR ----------------- UNKNOWN IS NULL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n"); 
        fflush(0);
    }
    return pix;
}
```

P.S. other jpegs not in the resource file are rendering fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Qt Label::setPixmap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309835/qt-labelsetpixmap-not-working/16310198#16310198)

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpixmap.html#isNull

The file you are loading is probably corrupt or has a zero width or zero height.  Try some other file in resources, to see if you are populating it correctly.

Also from the resources editor, you can right click on an element in there and get the resource path.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I just figured it out: I was creating the pixmap in a non-gui thread which was causing this error.

Comment: It used to only give a runtime warning on the Application output about that back in Qt 4.8.  I guess Qt finally stepped it up to a full failure.